# Adding items to arrays and keeping track of variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, arrays

Basically, I need to keep track of a variable in a POS system. When you click an item at the top, it adds it to the list in an array (pulled from a database), I need to set the "tally" at 1 (ie 1 item added), and when you click to add the item again, it checks the array of items in the list, and if it is there it then adds one to the "tally". I am unable to do this, and it just adds an item to an array, and then doesn't do anything after that. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <?
    // Connect database. 
    include("settings.php");
    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);
    ?>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>POS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Company</h1>
        <h4>User</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="pagination btn-group" id="items">
                    <? $sql = "SELECT itemname FROM items ORDER BY itemname ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $datacost = $row['price'];
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $itemname = $row['itemname'];

                        echo "<button class='btn btn-medium highlight-color-0' id='$id' item-name='$itemname' data-cost='$datacost'><div class='btn-image gears'></div><span class='btn-text'>$itemname</span>";
                    }

                    echo "</button>"; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h2>Totals</h2>
                <ul id="items">
                </ul>
                <h3 id="price">£0</h3>
                <button class="btn btn-large background-color-1">checkout</button>
                <button class="btn btn-large background-color-2">add to tab</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Set up an object for the order
            order =
            {
                ids: [],
                itemNums: [],
                total: 0,

                // Initialise things
                init: function()
                {
                    order.itemNums[0] = 0;

                    // Do something when someone clicks a button
                    $('#items button').click(function()
                    {
                        id = $(this).attr('id');
                        name = $(this).attr('item-name');
                        price = $(this).attr('data-cost');

                        // Add item to order
                        if ((order.itemNums[id] < 1) || (order.itemNums[id] == null))
                        {
                            order.itemNums[id] = 1;
                            order.addItemToOrder(id, name, price);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            order.itemNums[id]++;
                        }
                    });
                },

                addItemToOrder: function(id, name, price)
                {
                    $("ul#items").append("<div class='tag-remove'>" + name + "</div>");
                    $("ul#items").append("<div class='tag tag-rounded tag-padded background-color-1 light-text'>" + order.itemNums[id] + "</div><br>");
                    order.updateTotal(price);
                },

                updateTotal: function(price)
                {
                    order.total += price * order.itemNums[id];

                    $('h3#price').html("£" + parseFloat(order.total, 10).toFixed(2));
                }
            };

            $(function()
            {
                order.init();   
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you'd want to add a 'tally' variable before the order object, then increment it in the click function?

Comment: Would it need to be an array? Because there will be different items with different tallies

Comment: Ah perhaps I misunderstood, you so you want to tally how many of each item? For instance 2 oranges, 3 apples, 5 bananas, etc?

Comment: Yes, sticking with the fruit example, say there were buttons at the top to select ie apples oranges bananas pineapples, and when you click apples it adds it to the list. Then, when apples is clicked again, it changes it to x2, then x3 etc. Then if you click bananas it adds it below apples with x1. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The order object is being updated, but you change the HTML only if the element was not yet added to the order. So after `order.itemNums[id]++` you'd need to update the HTML, or just write a function that renders the whole order and call it after anything changes.

Comment: I suppose I would approach this a little differently. I'd create an Item object with ID, Name, Price, and Quantity that gets passed to an Order array. That way when you click the button you can loop through the Order array to see if that Item ID already exists, if theres a match increment the Quantity.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ev0yy5om/ sorry I don't have time to add explanation, but the items are kept in an object (to avoid a sparse array) and the HTML is re-rendered each change.

Comment: @powel How would I integrate this to properly pull from a database?